# Xamarin Studio: Hello World Template Won't Stop Being Used

Tags: c#, android, templates, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Every time I create a new project in Xamarin Studio (in my case, Android Applications), Xamarin Studio creates my project like normal, except creates a hello world template instead! So instead of my empty application, all that comes up is [this](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,_world/Images/00a.png). Now, all I have to do to get rid of it is refactor all my file so that everything goes back to default, but I think that this is screwing with the files, as there seems to be some folders missing from my projects, like some of the folders where I would place my various sized icons for various sized devices.

Is there some unknown template that I'm unaware of that needs to be disabled? I understand that some think that this may be a starting point and that it is 'okay' to just refactor until the project is good enough to work with, but what if I just want an empty template, where it returns an application that is ready and usable, but without all the hello world crap? Why is Xamarin Studio cursing me with Hello World?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am taking a mobile app class right now where we are using Xamarin for all of our apps.  This same question was asked and the instructor told us that 'Hello World' is the default.  Really simple to start fresh though.  Erase all the contents of `MainActivity.cs`, your main activity class, so that it resembles a new activity. For now keep `MainLauncher = true`.  Basically erase the `int` declaration, and everything in the `OnCreate()` method after `base.OnCreate(bundle);`. Then open Resources/layout/Main.axml. Click anywhere in the empty black box below the text and hit delete.  You'll see a display indicating that the layout is empty.  Rename the layout to whatever you want.  Everything remains from what you had at the start except the specific code for 'Hello World'.  I know this probably is not the answer you wanted, but I can assure you that nothing is being lost. This is a perfectly clean starting point.

Comment: Yeah, I talked to a few people and they all told me why it did it. I accepted your answer for future generations to see.